# Use bootstrap navbar in ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to use Bootstrap in my new ASP.Net MVC project, as you know the structure of Navbar is like:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you see the active Url have **active** class.
I want to know how can I sense the active url and get it active class?

I use MVC 3 with Razor.

Comment: Are you using routes for the urls ? If so you could test for the matching controller/action : check http://stackoverflow.com/q/4412310/1478467

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that you want to set the active item? (when you say 'get it active class')

See answer on this other almost identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354935/twitter-bootstrap-asp-net-masterpages-how-to-set-navbar-item-as-active-when-u), it does the job (although not the most optimal code).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var substr = url.split('/');
        var urlaspx = substr[substr.length-1];
        $('.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav li a').each(function () {
            if (this.href.indexOf(urlaspx) >= 0) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Surely this is something that ought to be done on the server side.

Answer (score -3):

You can use JQuery to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  alert( $('.nav').children('.active').html() );
}
```