# Twitter bootstrap + asp.net masterpages, navbar active item doesn't works for dropdown lists

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12364207/1977152) solution has worked wonderfully for me except for one glitch. It doesn't works for dropdown menu. (**I'm using Bootstrap v 2.1.1**)

Like this,

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           Account <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
               <a href="Login.aspx">Login</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="xxx">Register</a>
           </li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Shows something like this....(Attached below)

As you can see for the dropdown no menu title available and it is always selected. [image: No menu heading visible and always selected]

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: Bootstrap 2.1.1