# Active link in navigation bar when GET variables are present

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a wee problem. I know from answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813498/make-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-link-active?lq=1) how to have an `active` link on the navigation bar.

However, this doesn't work if there are GET variables after the link. So while my `<li>` gets `class = "active"` if I load `daily.php`, it **doesn't get the class** if I load `daily.php?project=4`.

The code I am using right now for the navigation bar and making a certain link active is this:

```
<?php
function echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
        echo 'class="active"';
}
?>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li <?php echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("daily") ?>><a href="daily.php">Daily</a></li>
<li <?php echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("weekly") ?>><a href="weekly.php">Weekly</a></li>
<li <?php echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("monthly") ?>><a href="monthly.php">Monthly</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

As I said, this doesn't work if instead of `daily.php` I load `daily.php?project=4`.

All help is welcome, and if you need any more code, please just ask!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a some modified function

```
<?php
function echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{       
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if (strpos($current_file_name,$requestUri)!==false)
        echo 'class="active"';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use strpos rather than "==". It will check if the URL contains the address you wanted.
Or you can split the URL using explode

```
$current_url = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $current_url[0] ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well as Pvb's answer! It is unfortunate that I cannot accept two answers...