# Changing navbar dynamically without (too much) repeating code

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a file called `header.php` which includes a bootstrap navbar header, is it possible to change for example the 'active' tab in the menu dynamically according to the specific page I am on?

> Header.php file:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Example Website</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active" id="page1">Page 1</li>
            <li id="page2">Page 2</li>
            <li id="page3">Page 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's say I include this with php into `page1.php`, `page2.php` and `page3.php`, 
How can I dynamically change the active tab from `header.php` to for example `Page 2` in case of being on page 2?

**Update:** 
I found a solution. Thanks to one of the 'duplicate' references.

Comment: *Yes,* it is possible. I could easily give you links from a Google search of "if current active page php" but feel you should be doing that. You may not have known what to look for, now you do ;-)

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I've added some code, to make it a bit more explaining, itself.

Comment: I can think of at least one way to do this in pure JS, one with a JS framework, and 3 or more in PHP.  What have *you* thought about?  Do you have an idea ... have you flow-charted the logic process?

Comment: I prefer to use PHP as much as it's possible to use. But otherwise I wouldn't mind to use jQuery instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Twitter Bootstrap navbar link active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813498/make-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-link-active)

Comment: @vanburen Thank you this actually helped me out.